# How do I get the correct ID (html) a control in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net

Everyone knows that the ID for all user controls changes upon the asp.net page is created.

```
<div id="ID-value" runat="server"></div>
```

becomes:

```
<div id="ct100$ID-value"></div>
```

This could be a pain in the ass I think, especially when you try to bind objects to javascripts. 
So.

Is there a way to get the correct ID as it is shown in the html page? so that I can manually bind this object to the java script?
(in other words: I want the "ct100$.....")
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like below in javascript

```
document.getElementById('<%=ID-value.ClientID%>')
```

or in jQuery

```
$('#<%=(ID-value).ClientID%>')
```

This is better because you can access elements directly with the actual id's in code-behind.

Comment: I was looking for <%=ID-value.ClientID%>, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ASP.net 4.0 or higher, you can try setting the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) to be static - this will prevent the Id from being written by ASP.net (but will not give you unique Ids for controls included inside other controls that bind multiple rows).

Comment: Also, if you are trying to get a reference to the control in JavaScript, the easiest option is to use a jQuery selector and the ID$= selector predicate.  For example, $('ID$=TextBox1') will find the control ct100$TextBox1.

Comment: Why would he set the ID of a div to the ID of another control?